# Application logs for support and analysis purpose

Tags: python

I am analyzing an existing Python code that runs into hundreds of line. Adding log per line to capture flow / understanding run time processing is painful - but then the current application logging is very poor by just using **print** data.

Hence for support purpose these are not enough as its difficult to understand without looking into code.

What is the best way of change these unstandard logs into at least something like -

Class Name - Method Name - Error Details **additional more details**

With small modifications - I also run into risk of breaking the flow if not dealt carefully.

Please let me know which application mechanism logging would be the best?

Comment: I though of same but wouldn't I would still need to add log statements in code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise you to type "Python /?" in a command prompt and see which possibilities you have (e.g. `python -v` gives a verbose output on the import statements in your code). Like this you might find a way of having more information without needing to modify your source code. Obviously I don't know if the information you get from `python -v` is the one you're looking for.

Comment: Meanwhile I looked a bit further and I have found a `trace` module, which you can use as follows: `python -m trace --trace  test.py`. It gives more information than you need but by this I just want to explain you that the way you launch your Python script gives you the opportunity to configure the way it the execution is logged/traced.

Answer (score 0):

I think probably decorators are your best option so you touch the code as less as possible.

First link redirects the standard stdout to a python standard logging module, so it would have the format you want if you specify it within the logger properties.

https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Redirects_stdout_printing_to_python_standard_logging.

https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Logging_decorator_with_specified_logger_.28or_default.29